# How to check if elements in a page already exist using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am building a chat app using flask socketio. So I am trying to implement chat history, but the problem I run into is that whenever a new user connects, the app sends the new user the chat history, as well as to the old user, thus resulting in duplicated chat history for the old user. I've tried everything server side, but I think the only way is through Javascript client side. Is there any way that when Javascript gets the chat history, could I make JS first check if that messages don't already exist on the page, and then append them?

Here is a screenshot on what is happening.
[visual representation of what's happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UhQs.png)

Code(Client-side Javascript)

```
  const socket = io.connect("http://127.0.0.1:5000");

socket.on('connect', function() {

  socket.emit('sync_messages', {
    dname: "{{dname}}"
  });

});
```

Code (Server-side Flask Socketio)

```
@socketio.on('sync_messages')
def handle_sync(data):
        socketio.emit('show_all_messages', messages)
```

Code (Client-side again)

```
socket.on('show_all_messages', function(data) {
 // console.log(data);
  len = data.length;
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    const newNode = document.createElement('div');
    newNode.innerHTML = data[i];
    document.getElementById('messages').appendChild(newNode);
  }

})
```

Comment: Can you please include the code what you are working on? It would be easier for the community to answer the question, thank you!

Comment: I have just added it, let me know if there's anything else I can help it.

Answer (score 0):

Really simple. 
You can any give any types of attribute to that element which you need to find and do

```
function checkElement(){
   if(document.querySelector(/*Selector*/)){
      return true;
   }
   else{return false;}
}
```

then just call this function when you need. document.querySelector in if statement will automatically look for you does html element exist or not

Comment: Okay, so I think this will work. So all the messages are in the div id "messages". I was wondering if I could first pull what is in div of "messages" and then compare it to the chat history, and then append?

Comment: @salmans911 actually I am not familiar with backend (server-side programming) so I don't know much chat history, but I think what you said should work

Comment: it's okay, I just used your code, and I'm figuring something out. thank youu!